# Number of inversions in an array of pairs of integers

Tags: algorithms

I have a problem like this:

we have an array of elements like this :

```
(a0,b0)
(a1,b1)
.
.
.
(an,bn)
```

and I wanna find the number of elements which have one of this two condition:

`1) if ai>aj and bi<bj then:count:=count+1`

or

`2) if ai<aj and bi>bj then:count:=count+1`

I've already found an algorithm that is $O(n^2)$, but I need the  faster algorithm.

**Example:**
suppose we have this:

```
(1,5)
(4,7)
(8,2)
```

I wanna find the number of time that condition satisfied, so
1<8 and 2<5 so condition is satisfied but 1<4 and 5<7 so condition is
not satisfied.

Comment: (Essentially) solved on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337664/counting-inversions-in-an-array

Comment: A divide-and-conquer $O(nlog(n))$ algorithm for inversions counting is described in the book "Algorithm Design" by Jon Kleinberg and Eva Tardos, section 5.3.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/137100/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4076036/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize the problem like so (using `a = [1,4,8], b = [5,7,2]`):
[image: crude drawing]

As you can see, I have sorted `a`, with each element pointing to a position in `b` sorted in reverse. All we need to do now is iterate over `a`, counting how many previous indices were lower than us. We can can compute that with a Fenwick tree, all in $O(nlog(n))$. Here is a python implementation:

```python
import bisect

def query(bit, i):
    ret = 0
    while i > 0:
        ret += bit[i]
        i -= i & -i
    return ret


def update(bit, i, delta):
    while i < len(bit):
        bit[i] += delta
        i += i & -i


def csFindInversions2(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)

    def solve(a, b):
        tmp = sorted(b)
        lut = [
            len(b) - bisect.bisect(tmp, b[i])
            for i in sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i])
        ]
        bit = [0]*(len(a) + 1)
        ret = 0
        for i in lut:
            ret += query(bit, i)
            update(bit, i+1, 1)
        return ret
    return solve(a, b) + solve(b, a)
```

Note that this solution does not account for duplicates.